# Is there a way I can avoid imperial ships?

Tags: final-fantasy-15

Whenever I am traveling on foot, imperial ships will fly by and drop down troops for me to fight. In a normal situation, this is no big deal and I will fight or flee to continue with my travels.

However this will also occur when I am doing a quest that requires me to locate and pick up items. This is an inconvenience as I cannot pick up items while in combat and I have to kill them before I can continue.

Is there a way I can "hide" and allow the ships to by pass my location?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few ways you can really handle imperial ships.

- First and by far the most profitable, have some spells ready in the imperials weakness (fire or ice I cannot remember which). Watch the dropship and throw out your spell the second they land on the ground killing pretty much all of the troops instantly and leaving a few stragglers with little to no HP. I recommend this cause you do get a **lot** of XP by doing this but it can still get time consuming.
- The second which is more of what you are asking is to simply run out of the area of the dropship, imperial troops should despawn if you get far enough away from their spawn point but this isn't always a guarentee.

Again though while you can run from them, if you prepare for their drop and throw their weakness at them you can get boatloads of free XP for little to no work.

Hope this helps.